# pointer to struct contains pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I am writing code in c++ but I have a problem in pointers, please help me!

the error is: Unhandled exception at 0x010613af in Grid.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct test{
    int test_num;
    int * test_ptr;
};

struct test1{
    int test1_num;
    test* test1_ptr;
};

void main()
{
    test1 tt;
    tt.test1_num=0;
    tt.test1_ptr=0;
    int  * t = tt.test1_ptr->test_ptr;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly as it should be. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: `main` returns `int` in C++, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
int  * t = tt.test1_ptr->test_ptr
```

Is dereferencing a null pointer. You set it to null in the line:

```
tt.test1_ptr=0;
```

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 things wrong:

1. main must return an int.
2. you are dereferencing a null pointer.

   ```
   int main()
   {
       test1 tt;
       tt.test1_num=0;
       tt.test1_ptr=0;
       int  * t // = tt.test1_ptr->test_ptr;
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If `tt.test1_ptr` is 0 (i.e. NULL), you cannot deference it, it is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `tt.test1_ptr->test_ptr` you should use `tt.test1_ptr.test_ptr`. 
Remember that operator `->` return actual value which pointer lead to, in your case address 0 has no value/you dont have access to that.

Answer (score 0):

First you intialize `test1_ptr` to 0, then you try to de-reference it before it is pointing to anything.

```
tt.test1_ptr=0;
int  * t = tt.test1_ptr->test_ptr;
```